# How return a object inside a done function while the function expected to have a return value in typescript?

Tags: function, typescript, return-value

a simple function in typescript:

```
callAPI ():JSONObject{
    let j:JSONObject;
    $.ajax().done((data, textStatus, jqXHR)=>{
        //some operation around data
        j = data;
        return j;
    });
}
```

The error is very straight forward,

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

I just don't know how to fix since i can't return that object when the ajax is not finish. Who knows how to deal with this situation?

Comment: There is a reason $.ajax() doesn't return an HTTP response: it can't, since an AJAX request is, by definition, asynchronous. All you can do is return void and take a callback as argument (just like $.ajax() does), or return a Promise or an Observable.

Comment: @JBNizet It works, I added a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just return a value as the ajax request is async. There are a few options:

(1) Use async function:

```
async function callAPI(): JSONObject {
    return new Promise<JSONObject>(resolve => {
        $.ajax().done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

(2) Return a promise:

```
function callAPI(): Promise<JSONObject> {
    return new Promise<JSONObject>(resolve => {
        $.ajax().done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

(3) Pass a callback instead of retuning a value:

```
function callAPI(cb: (JSONObject) => void): void {
    $.ajax().done((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
        cb(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is why we need async/await in typescript as in .Net

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with .net but you have the async feature in typescript, as my first example shows

Comment: FYI: you shouldn't wrap everything in a `new Promise` just to get `resolve` and `reject` functions. Instead, make use of the fact that `$.ajax()` returns a thenable that you can `await`, e.g. `let data = await $.ajax(...)` This also handles error propagation, which is otherwise lost in your code examples.